# show active color when page loads for the first time - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have two buttons and their role are to show their respective data when one of the buttons is clicked.

```
<div>
  <h1>Ng-show & ng-hide</h1>
  <p class="description">Click on the "show"-link to see the content.</p>
  <button ng-click="showme=true" ng-class="{activeButton: showme == true}">Show</button>
  <button ng-click="showme=false" ng-class="{activeButton: showme == false}">Hide</button> 

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p ng-hide="showme">It will appear here!</p>
    <h2 ng-show="showme">This is mah content, yo!</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, I added the ng-class to show an active color(say 'red') when a button is clicked and the other should go back to it's original color(blue).  When the page loads, the first thing I see is the message "It will appear here!". Which is fine but the button that represents("Hide") this message doesn't have the active color red.

How can I set the active color by default when the page loads for the first time to this button?  I would like to keep the toggle functionality still, I should be able to click a button and see the active color.

Your help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: `ng-init` or define `showme` in controller...

Comment: When the page loads for the first time, variable `showme` does not have any value, so it equal to `undefined`. With the above code, change `ng-class` value to `{activeButton: showme}` and `{activeButton: !showme}` would works

Comment: Thanks guys, this really helped!  Brand new to AngularJS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Null` and `Undefined` Types are **strictly equal(==)** to themselves and **abstractly equal(==)** to each other.[[*Ref*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)]

In your `ng-class` statements, neither of the condition is being satisfied hence `class` is not applied. In `ng-show/hide`, `undefined` is evaluated as `false` hence *"It will appear here!"* is being shown.

Set the value of `showme` as `true` in controller

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.showme = false;
})
```

```css
.activeButton {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h1>Ng-show & ng-hide</h1>
  <p class="description">Click on the "show"-link to see the content.</p>
  <button ng-click="showme=true" ng-class="{activeButton: showme}">Show</button>
  <button ng-click="showme=false" ng-class="{activeButton: !showme}">Hide</button>

  <div class="wrapper">
    <p ng-hide="showme">It will appear here!</p>
    <h2 ng-show="showme">This is mah content, yo!</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: simpler to just evaluate `showme` in view as boolean without `==`

Comment: @charlietfl – Is edit fine ? Did you mean the same ?

Comment: Yes... less to write and does same thing

Comment: @charlietfl – I agree but few beginners may find it difficult to understand(_I guess_).. ;)